# Why does SHA256Managed().ComputeHash() return a different hash than from what external tools produce?

Tags: c#, sha

As a personal exercise, I have been playing around with generating SHA256 hashes in a small program I am writing. I have an arbitrary bitmap file on my computer that I have loaded into my program. There is a problem somewhere that I can't identify. The hash returned by my program is `5EFFCC89AEA1922485CFA721194320D8895A4F31AC4AA5134AC2104C528033BA` but when I run 7-Zip's SHA256 tool on the exact same file, it returns `D78859AD5651EB23A771C4763D03E65D64550C0660F7E182668586398CF02BF9`. Here's my code:

```
var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\1\image.bmp");
var stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
var hashedBytes = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(stream);
var hash = string.Concat(hashedBytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
```

The only code that looks like it could be causing a problem is the conversion of the image into a `MemoryStream` object. But if I understand correctly, this is effectively just a byte array, so it doesn't seem like it should be changing any data.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you're trying to compute the hash of a file, why not use a `FileStream` instead of first materializing it as a bitmap, then making it a stream again? As far as I know that's not guaranteed to be an idempotent operation (even if the hash calculation was otherwise perfect).

Comment: Do you get same results running more than once?

Comment: I think you should reset the stream to its start position. And to get comparable results take  the hash from the uninterpreted file and not from the bitmap.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry for the confusion. You make a good point and I appreciate the input. However, this program generates bitmap images and I will be computing the hash on them. But while trying to figure out the hash discrepancy issue, I used a file on disk to test with, so that I could minimize the variability in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have written the image to your memory stream, its position will be set to the end of the stream. If you pass it to `ComputeHash()` in that state, it will have no bytes to hash.

Therefore you must reset the position to zero before passing the stream to `ComputeHash()`:

```
var image  = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\1\image.bmp");
var stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
stream.Position = 0;
var hashedBytes = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(stream);
var hash        = string.Concat(hashedBytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
```

Comment: Resetting the stream position was the issue. I did not know this about streams. Thanks for teaching me something!